# Swagger doesn't generate reference link for "parameters"

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

In YAML file I have this:

```
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          description: Body of the request.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MinimalProgresstrailEntry'
```

and it's rendered to this:

[image]:

it doesn't render the reference for the body. It works fine for the `responses` but not for `parameters`.

reference definitions:

```
MinimalProgresstrailEntry:
type: object
properties:
  memoText:
    type: string
  type:
    type: string
    enum:
      - memo
      - attachment
      - link
```

Comment: Could you post the referenced definitions ?

Comment: @NelsonG.I posted it to the question.

Comment: I'll post a response with a full swagger file, could you check it because it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Following swagger file works on [swagger-editor](http://editor.swagger.io) :

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: "0.0.0"
  title: title
paths:
  /persons:
    get:
      description: test
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          description: Body of the request.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MinimalProgresstrailEntry'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MinimalProgresstrailEntry'
definitions:
  MinimalProgresstrailEntry:
   type: object
   properties:
    memoText:
      type: string
    type:
      type: string
      enum:
        - memo
        - attachment
        - link
```

Comment: Yes, it works on swagger editor, but the strange thing is it doesn't work in real implementation. May be the plugin has some bugs, I'm not sure.